# Specify the Log Group for API-Gateway using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am using Terraform to work with API-Gateway and I enabled CloudWatch Logs. However, I would like to customise the name of the Log Group so it's more related to the project the Log Group is responsible for because "API-Gateway-Execution-Logs_xxxxxx/stage" isn't a very relatable name. Especially if you plan to deploy several applications.

So I was wondering if it's possible to specify the name of the Log Group anywhere in one of the Terraform AWS provider configuration elements so I can put the Log Group that want.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can not customize the log group name with API Gateway.

Comment: I'm not sure I am aware of relevant docs; this is based on my experience. Do you know of any documents that state as such? Are you suggesting I link to the API documentation and describe that it DOES NOT include a log group name option?

Comment: I guess https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=228989 is reasonably official? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-logging.html#apigateway-cloudwatch-log-formats and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/view-cloudwatch-log-events-in-cloudwatch-console.html also both allude to it not being customisable too but the forums thread is probably a clearer answer and is a response from someone on the API Gateway team.

Comment: I found this comment, but I'm unsure whether it does what I want: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/2406#issuecomment-347645154

Comment: Thanks for helping me to provide better responses! Appreciate the coaching.